# Problems: Lagrange multipliers... $f(x,y)=x^2y^3(1-x-y)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I need calculate the absolute end point of the function $f(x,y)=x^2y^3(1-x-y)$ when  $K=\{(x,y)\epsilon\mathbb{R}^2: |x|+|y| \leq 1 \}$. So $K$ is a rotated square, how I have to calculate that I started calculating the relative point, but when I try calculate the absolute point I don't have idea how I can do it.

---

To the absolute point: I consider $F: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow\mathbb{R} / \  F(x,y,\lambda)=f(x,y)+\lambda(|x|+|y|-1)$ but the lagrange system is impossible to solve, I need help! thanks

Comment: Since the boundary is not differentiable everywhere, you should restrict attention to the four segments which make it up. For instance, one of these is $y=1-x,0 \leq x \leq 1$.

Comment: Divide into four cases to figure out whether there are any extreme values along the edges, then just check the function values at the four corners.

Comment: yes, I divide that but I have that $K_{1}=\{y\geq x-1\}; K_{2}=\{y\leq x+1\}; K_{3}=\{y\leq -x+1\}; K_{4}=\{y\geq -x-1\}; $ I said that it is impossible to solve because I divide that before

Comment: You should write out the work that you've done, so we can more easily see where exactly you get stuck.

Comment: Ok, If I consider that, that is, $K_1,\ ...,\ K_4$, I will put an example what I did... I will have with all $"K_i"$. I consider $K_1=\{(x,y)\epsilon\Bbb{R}^2/y\geq x-1\}$, so I have $F(x,y,\lambda)=x^2y^3(1-x-y)+\lambda (y-x+1)$ $$2xy^3(1-x-y)-x^2y^3-\lambda=0, \ (1)$$ $$ 3x^2y^2(1-x-y)-x^2y^3+\lambda=0, \ (2)$$ $$ y=x-1,\ (3)$$ when I sustitute $(3)$ in $(1)$ and $(2)$ I get a new system of $x, \lambda$ but it is impossible to solve.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, find the extremae of $f$ in the interior of $K$.  Then look at the boundary of $K$. In neither of the four cases multipliers are needed as you can solve either equation for $y$ and substitute the solution back in $f$.  Don't forget to check the edges.

Lagrange is needed if it's difficult or impossible to solve the restriction for one variable.

Comment: You're welcome.